# Summernote onpaste doesnot working

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

I don't know what's the actual reason.. *Onpaste* function doesn't work

And here is my code

**HTML**

```
<textarea name='desc' rows='5' id='editor' class='form-control editor'></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
    $('.editor').summernote({
        onkeydown:function(e){
            var num = $('.editor').code().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").replace(/( )/, " ").length;
            // alert(num);
            var key = e.keyCode;
            allowed_keys = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46]
            if($.inArray(key, allowed_keys) != -1)
                return true
            else if(num >= 500){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        },
        onKeyup: function (e) {
            var num = $('.editor').code().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").replace(/( )/, " ").length;
            var key = e.keyCode;
            allowed_keys = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46]
            if($.inArray(key, allowed_keys) != -1)
                return true
            else if(num >= 500){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        },
        onPaste: function (e) {
            var t = e.currentTarget.innerText;
            alert(t);
        },
        callbacks : {
            onPaste : function (e)  {
                alert('onpaste');
                var num = $('.editor').code().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").replace(/( )/, " ").length;
                var key = e.keyCode;
                allowed_keys = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46]
                if($.inArray(key, allowed_keys) != -1)
                    return true
                else if(num >= 500){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here, the *Keyup & Keydown* function working properly except the onpaste function.. Please someone help me out of this.. how to do that limited numbers of restriction also in *onpaste* function..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Updated a fiddle here. it seems it works fine. what version you are using. you can tell your console output or any error:

`code` https://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/dtgr5q29/95/

one more reson can be, if you click on "Prevent this page from creating additional alerts". it will prevent from your page to get more alerts. You can use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` and check on console.

let know if it help.

Comment: I din't get any error in my console and I dont know how to find the version of js file..Since it's already updated in my project folder by someone else.. :(

Comment: what output you want when someone paste data ?

Comment: Like wise in my keyup & keydown function I need to restrict number of characters to be paste

Comment: can you give a testcase ?

Comment: even *console.log()* din't work for me.. I think onpaste function is not working properly

Comment: any test case ?

Comment: If user type certain characters, it should end after certain limit.. In my script the *keyup & keydown* function restrict the typing character after it reach _500_ .Like that I need to restrict the user while copy paste content from somewhere else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136346/discussion-between-deepak-sharma-and-suganya-rajasekar).

Comment: how is this concluded? i'm stuck here too. i simply put the exact example as displayed in Deep Drive but it ain't working. need help please.